# Which synchronize statements are unnecessary here?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

#### First the code fragments...

```
final class AddedOrders {
    private final Set<Order> orders = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
    private final Set<String> ignoredItems = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet(); 
    private boolean added = false;

    public synchronized void clear() {
        added = false;
    }

    public synchronized void add(Order order) {
        added = orders.add(order);
    }

    public synchronized void remove(Order order) {
        if (added) orders.remove(order); 
    }

    public synchronized void ban(String item) {
        ignoredItems.add(item);
    }

    public synchronized boolean has(Order order) {
        return orders.contains(order);
    }

    public synchronized Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public synchronized boolean ignored(String item) {
        return ignoredItems.contains(item);
    }
}

private final AddedOrders added = new AddedOrders();


...
    boolean subscribed;
    int i = 10;
    synchronized (added) {
        while (!(subscribed = client.getSubscribedOrders().containsAll(added.getOrders())) && (i>0)) {
           Helper.out("...order not subscribed yet (try: %d)", i);
           Thread.sleep(200);
           i--;
        }
    }
```

#### What I'd like to know...

Could someone point out which `synchronized` are not necessary?

Of course this is not the full code but assume that in the full project that all methods are called, and that some combinations of methods are called in the ***check value first, then modify*** style

`added`(the class) is accessed by multiple`Thread`s

`client` is part of an external Server API, that I'm not entirely sure if it is Thread-Safe yet but I think it must be

`ConcurrentHashSet` is a `google guava Class` but it is based on `ConcurrentHashMap` apparently and the docs say it carries all the same concurrency guarantees.

But I don't really understand completely what those guarantees all are, even though I did some reading. Namely I know it's not ok to just check and set a value in a synchronized `HashMap` (without synchronizing on the `synchronized Map` using a `synchronized block`), however I do not know if you can do that in `ConcurrentHashMap` or not (without synchronizing on the `ConcurrentHashMap` using a `synchronized block`).

Comment: "added is accessed by multipleThreads" Then any method accessing `added` needs to be synchronized, so the first three *are* necessary.

Comment: ah crap, I fell victim to bad naming (for the purposes of asking a question at least)... I was referring to `AddedOrders added` not the `added` flag

Comment: @ycomp: i'm not clear what good the added flag does, actually.

Comment: @NathanHughes you know, you have a point.. looks like it is a remnant from before,when Sets were not being used. Now I could just check the Set instead. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @NathanHughes actually it does have a purpose, it is just buried in the code using it (which is quite long), but good thing that you pointed it out because it (the added flag) is not Thread Safe.. this particular class and related code was first created without thinking about Threads.. so it worked just fine in a Single Thread scenario )

Answer (score 2):

The only cases in your code where you really need synchronized are the ones where you test or update the added flag. You need the synchronized block to make sure that changes to the flag are visible across threads, and you also need to make sure that the added flag change is made in step with the change to the orders data structure. The synchronized keyword keeps another thread from barging in and doing something in between checking the flag and changing the data structure (the remove method could be broken like this if you remove the synchronization).

The code toward the end seems problematic because you're locking on the added object and then not letting go of the lock, there's not an opportunity for any other thread to make the changes that the thread is looking for. Although it looks like you're waiting for another object to change, so this criticism may be invalid. Sleeping with a lock held seems dangerous, though. This kind of thing is why Object#wait releases the lock it acquired.

Also note that since you're passing references out to the Orders set, code outside this class can add orders. You should do something to protect this internal data, like returning it wrapped in an immutableSet so callers can't make changes.

In general synchronization is used when you want to impose some granularity on changes, where you have 2 or more changes you want made together, without possibility of interleaving. An example is a check-then-act sequence where you execute some code that makes a change based on the value of something else, and you don't want some other thread to execute in between the check and the action (so the decision to act could be made, then the condition that allowed that action changes, so that the action could be invalid). If individual values are changed but they are unrelated, then you can make them volatile or use Atomic variables, and reduce the amount of locking you have to do.

It's a valid point that the synchronized keyword could be removed in cases like the clear method, where the only thing that changes is the added flag, which could be made volatile. The purpose of the added flag continues to elude me. Anything that enters a value that's already present can turn the flag back to false, it's not apparent that reasoning about any action based on what the current value of the flag makes any sense if this structure is getting modified concurrently.

Without knowing the exact context it's hard to say, but in general, classes created without considering their being used with multiple threads probably need to be reworked extensively before being used in a concurrent environment.

Comment: can I ask if your answer is still the same (about the `added` flag), seeing that I had forgotten that I had 2 variables named added.. and what I mean was this whole class (variable also called `added`) can be accessed my multiple threads - not just the `added` flag ? - it was a stupid mistake I made when posting, not to rename one of those variables

Comment: @ycomp: yes, i was referring to your added flag.

Comment: in this synchronized block, there is nothing that reads or writes the added flag, so I guess this block is not necessary?

Comment: There is also no need in synchronizing `clear()` method, if one mark `added` as a `volatile`.

Comment: @Denis: I don't think so, because that doesn't force the two changes to be atomic, interleaving is possible. (I'm unclear about what the flag does and I suspect it needs to be refactored out as part of a redesign for multithreaded access.)

Comment: @NathanHughes: based on the code provided, I'd say there is no possibility of race condition. Methods `clear()` and `add()` could be interleaved because the new value of the `added` flag doesn't depend on the old one. The same true for `clear()` and `remove()` methods. Can you provide scenario what could go wrong if we remove `synchronized` block from `clear()` method?

Comment: @Denis: that's a good point that the provided code does not have that dependency.